# Insert nodes in order in Linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to write a member function, `Link* add_ordered (Link* n)` , that adds a node in a lexicographical order in a list, however, when I try to print the ordered list only the last added node is printed, i.e. `"Poseidon"`.

Here is how my node interface looks like:

```
struct God {
    // public members of God
    std::string name;
    std::string mythology;
    std::string vehicle;
    std::string weapon;

    // constructor
    God (std::string n, std::string m, std::string v = " ", std::string w = " ")
        : name(n), mythology(m), vehicle(v), weapon(w) { }
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Link {
public:
    God god;

    // consructor
    Link (God g, Link* p = 0, Link* s = 0)
        : god(g), prev(p), succ(s) { } 

    // modifying member functions
    Link* insert (Link* n);
    Link* add (Link* n);
    Link* add_ordered (Link* n);
    Link* erase (void);
    Link* find (const std::string& v);

    // non - modifying member functions
    Link* advance (int n);

    const Link* find (const std::string& n) const;

    Link* previous () { return prev; }
    Link* next () { return succ; }

private:
    Link* prev;
    Link* succ;
};
```

Member function used in `add_ordered()`:

```
Link* Link::insert (Link* n) {

    if (n == 0) return this;
    if (this == 0) return n;

    n->succ = this;
    n->prev = prev;

    if (prev) prev->succ = n;

    prev = n;

    return n;
}
```

Finally, here is the function that performs the node ordering:

```
Link* Link::add_ordered (Link* n) {

    // check if nodes valid
    if (n == 0) return this;
    if (this == 0) return n;

    // pointer to this object
    Link *p = this;

    // order in lexicographically increasing order in terms of link's god's name
    while (p) {

        // if new node value smaller than the one in current node, insert before current node.
        if (n->god.name < p->god.name){
            insert(n);
            break;

        // otherwise go to previous node in the list
        } else { 
            p = prev;
        }
    } 

    // return the newly added, ordered Link
    return n;
}
```

Here is how I try to create an ordered doubly linked list:

```
int main () {

    // God(name(n), mythology(m), vehicle(v), weapon(w)) 
    // Greek mythology list of Gods

    Link* greek_gods = new Link(God("Zeus", "Greek", "", "lightning"));
    greek_gods = greek_gods->add_ordered(new Link(God("Hera", "Greek" )));
    greek_gods = greek_gods->add_ordered(new Link(God("Athena", "Greek")));
    greek_gods = greek_gods->add_ordered(new Link(God("Ares", "Greek")));
    greek_gods = greek_gods->add_ordered(new Link(God("Poseidon", "Greek" )));

   // print the list
   std::cout <<"{";

   while (greek_gods) {

       std::cout << greek_gods->god.name <<", "
                 << greek_gods->god.mythology <<", "
                 << greek_gods->god.vehicle <<", "
                 << greek_gods->god.weapon;

       // I've tried both directions, using greek_gods->next()
       if (greek_gods = greek_gods->previous()) std::cout <<'\n';
   }

   std::cout <<"}";
}
```

I've been trying for some time now to make it work, unsuccessfully, so any help would be much appreciated. I really can't see what is wrong with `add_ordered()`.

---

P.S. If I create the same list using `add()` or `insert()`, the whole list gets printed perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the remarks of @Frerich Raabe, the function `add_ordered()` got modified so that  always returns the starting node of the list. Additionally, new conditional, `if`, statement is added to check whether the new node is already in order and to add it in front of the list if so:

```
Link* Link::add_ordered (Link* n) {

    // check if nodes valid
    if (n == 0) return this;
    if (this == 0) return n;

    // pointer to this object
    Link *p = this;

    // if node already in order, add it in front of the list
    if (n->god.name < p->god.name) {
        add(n);

        // return current first node of the list
        return n;
    }

    // traverse existing list till new node's name smaller than current node's
    while (!(n->god.name < p->god.name) && p) {

        // previous node
        Link* temp = p;

        // if last node's name is smaller than new node's, add new at the end 
        if (!(p = p->prev)) {
            n->prev = nullptr;
            n->succ= temp;

            temp->prev = n;
            return this;
        }
    } 

    // add n in front of current node
    n->succ = p->succ;
    n->prev = p;

    if (p->succ){
        p->succ->prev = n;
   }

   p->succ = n;

   // return current first node
   return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Link::add_ordered` always returns its argument (or `this` in case the argument is null, that branch is not executed in your case though). Hence, all the

```
greek_gods = greek_gods->add_ordered(new Link(God("Hera", "Greek" )));
```

lines in your program will constantly make `greek_gods` point to the inserted link.

Comment: Should I _"rewind"_ `greek gods` to point to an end link before using it to print the list? The think is that only the last node seems to exist, detached from any other nodes...

Comment: Should I point `greek_gods` at the beginning of the list, after each insertion of a node in the right position?

Comment: Should it be `void add_ordered()?`

Comment: I don't know (but my guess is: no, `add_ordered` should not return `void`). You need to decide what the return value indicates. My impression is that you want it to be the new start of the list. I.e. in a call `a = b->add_ordered(c);`, the value of `a` will either be `b` (in case the added link `c` is greater than `b`) or it will be `c` (in case the added link is smaller than `b`).

Comment: ...hence, `add_ordered` should either `return *this;` or `return n;`. The former should happen if the given link is greater than `*this`. The latter should happen if the given link is smaller than `*this` (i.e. it becomes the new head of the list).